# Problems in loading a native library In Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am required to load two `.lib` files (written in C) to my java project and my intention is to write a wrapper on top of those libraries.

In my Eclipse I added the below line as a VM argument:

```
-Djava.library.path=D:\GTS\Ots\WS\streaming-tutorial\lib
```

and in my Java program I am trying to load the library using below code:

System.loadLibrary("client_api_jni");

but while executing the same I got below error:

> ```
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no client_api_jni in java.library.path
> ```

Comment: A .lib file is not a shared library. Do you *have* a shared library? And, if so, what is the *name* of your native shared library? And does this agree with what is stated as being expected by the Javadoc of `System.loadLibrary()`?

Comment: @EJP U mean a .dll file required for the same

Answer (score -2):

In order to set java.library.path you can provide -Djava.library.path=C:\Windows to set it in Windows. By the way, it's little different in Eclipse, which we will see in next section, which shows three places to set java.library.path in Eclipse.

1. You can set java.library.path in Eclipse by providing native library location for you libraries inside "java build path". Just follow below steps :

   ```
   1.1) Select Project ==> Properties ==> Java Build Path ==> Libraries 
        ==> JRE System Library ==> Native library location ==> Edit
   1.2) Edit will open a dialog box, which allows you to choose an 
        external folder, or a workspace location, to find native libraries
   ```
2. Similar to above steps, you can also set native library location, which will then converted into java.library.path by Eclipse, into source tab. Each source folder allows you to specify a native library location.

   ```
   1.1) Open Java Build Path as shown in above step, then choose Source tab
   1.2) Each Source folder has one native library location, select and 
        edit them to include your native libraries
   ```

3) Third way to set java.library.path is by using VM arguments. 
Here you will need to ensure that you are putting library name in double quotes.
Open Run Configurations or Debug Configuration of your project and provide -Djava.library.path="native library path" in Arguments tab, under VM arguments.

Comment: Here I tried the third option that is setting it through VM argument.But it failed

Comment: The question clearly states that the OP is already using `-Djava.library.path`.

Comment: You will need to try the path putting library in to (double quotes) "client_api_jni "

Comment: The question clearly states that he is already using double quotes. If he wasn't, his code wouldn't compile, let alone execute, let alone throw `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.` And you don't put a native library *name* into `java.library.path`: you put *paths.* Please stop this.